# How to check for empty Arguments in Prolog?

Tags: prolog, arguments

I'm new to prolog and could use some help.
Currently, I have to make a program that concat the last character of two strings.

For example,

```
    ?- termCat(with,spaghetti,T).
    T=hi
```

I was wondering how can I account for one of the arguments being nonexistant.
For instance I'm hoping to catch something like this...

```
   ?- termCat( , spaghetti,T).
   T = i
```

Comment: You can do something like termCat(_,spaghetti,T) and check for instance if the first argument is ground/variable or not

Comment: Do you mean an empty atom, which is represented by `''`, or an unbound argument?

Answer (score 0):

I use this pattern for 'default arguments' (the C++ feature, kind of). Depending on your use case and Prolog system, you should adapt as required. Beware that var/1, nonvar/1, !/0 are **impure** builtins that could interfere in unexpected ways with the resolution process. The cut (that is, !/0) is implicit in ->/2.

```erlang
termCat(X,Y,T) :-
  (var(X) -> X=with;true),
  (var(Y) -> Y=spaghetti;true),
  etc etc.
```

In SWI-Prolog, you can require arguments are not free - for instance - using [assertion](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=assertion/1)/1 from library(debug):

```erlang
:- use_module(library(debug)).
termCat(X,Y,T) :-
  assertion((nonvar(X),nonvar(Y))),
  etc etc.
```